# Action bar title is not aligning properly, android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I am using toolbar with in my app

This is my code

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

My XML

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/appColor"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/MyDarkToolbarStyle" />
```

Styles

```
   <style name="MyDarkToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/PopupMenuStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenuStyle" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left|center</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

This is how it looks

[image]

As you can see the the title text is not aligned either the navigation drawer

Comment: Does it work with the default style?

Comment: I had to add the following <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item> to my style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also same problem , it solve by using

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

For more details read issues on 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77874

Answer (score 1):

I use this, i put my own TextView and style it as i wish:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/materialToolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:shadowDrawable="@drawable/header_shadow"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--app:theme declaration will make sure that your text and items are using solid colors-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="..."
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:focusable="false" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then inside `Activity`, i hide default title. I also change typeface too:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
        toolbarTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        //toolbarTitle.setTypeface(((Itu) getApplication()).getToolbarTypeFace());
        toolbarTitle.setText(R.string.title_activity_course_list);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the following on the toolbar widget already:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

I ended up adding the following to the toolbar style:

```
<item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
```

This allowed my title to be centered vertically properly.